# How to deal with iterative edits/debugging completely changing a question?

Tags: discussion

The question [In Xilinx Vivado, simulation mismatch between behavioral and post-synthesis implementations](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/255974/in-xilinx-vivado-simulation-mismatch-between-behavioral-and-post-synthesis-impl) has been [revised](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/255974/revisions) to cover now three different problems:

1. critical synthesis warning on `temp_reg`
2. inferred latch for `slow_reg`
3. "noise present" on clock

The question has covered two points of Verilog that's poorly written (and almost-chaotically formatted) for correct synthesize and now wants to address a simulation issue that, given the user's comments, may be on refactored code.

The first answer, previously accepted, is now out of date. My answer, currently accepted, is also out of date. Effectively, this Q&A has turned into a one-OP-post forum for debugging the code. What should be done with this question?

Additional example: [Verilog: Shift Register with feedback loop](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/256449/verilog-shift-register-with-feedback-loop) seems to have been repeatedly skipped in the First Posts review queue (by me included) so much that I've seen and skipped it again. Again, it's an HDL debugging question that seems to be developing as a moving target for answers.

Comment: Personally I would make collaborative debugging questions offtopic. Currently I mostly downvote them on grounds of being not useful as they interfere with their goal of building a Q&A style database of knowledge. Solving one debugging problem for a specific person is unlikely to help anyone else. Some of these warrant the close as being too broad too. Sometimes there is an exceptional case that can be slightly reworded to be turned into a question about debugging techniques though, that will help future people  (e.g. turning "what is wrong here" into "how do I measure to find what is wrong")

Comment: @PlasmaHH can you change your comment into an answer?

Comment: This seems like something for the mods to deal with.  One possibility might be to roll back any edit that transforms a question into a different one, and tell the asker to ask a new question instead.  This sort of thing is grossly unfair to those taking the time to write good answers.  Perhaps the OP should be banned from asking questions for a week to get the point across.

Answer (score 2):

If the edits have changed the question to the point where little makes sense, I generally roll it back and comment that a new question has been posted.  If the OP re-rolls it back, flag it for moderator attention.

My favorite was a situation where the OP had lost asking privilege, and completely edited the question to ask something else. -- https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/227171/revisions

Comment: That... That's persistence for posting material...